# What type of data management system should I use for a OOP Javascript web application?

Tags: javascript, xml, database, oop

I'm in the process of building and designing my first Javascript OOP web application and I'm wondering what kind of data structure / management system would be best to use. I know the interaction between Javascript and XML is good and fairly easy, but XML isn't meant to be used as a database.

Is it better to form a combination of both? Have a server-side language (PHP) generate XML and have it then be read by JS?

Or am I heading in the wrong direction with this?

Comment: ...best to use for what? This is an extremely general question as it stands.

Comment: any recommendations based on the extremely limited and vague question will result in purely speculative and biased answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript itself doesn't do queries....it needs a helper like PHP, .net, or Java.  It can traverse XML or JSON just fine like you say, but sending colossal XML documents with all possible data when only small amounts of the data is actually required will lead to massive overhead that will bring your app to its knees.  It's the definition of lack-of-scalability.

My personal preference is JQuery Ajax talking to a PHP backend (transactions via JSON).  If I'm dealing with the presentation of large datasets I'll always page the information server-side and pipeline it (load data ahead of and behind the current view to reduce transactions), and usually present in via jQuery DataTables.  Grids are always your friend with large amounts of data.  Again, personal preference, but I make heavy use of jQuery UI for layout and presentation, and I do write custom Javascript for the "nifty" one-off type things that come up.  Again, any server language you have access to and are comfortable with will suffice, as Javascript is language agnostic.

Javascript can get out of hand in a hurry.  I'd recommend that unless you have a ton of time on your hands that you focus on clean presentation via something baseline like HTML with judicious use of Javascript and CSS for progressive enhancement.  Think about the user before you go crazy with motion, dynamic elements, etc.  Don't forget the old adage, "80% of the people only use 20% of the functionality"  Nail that 20% cleanly before going to town on flashy javascript fluff.  Your users will thank you!

Answer (score 1):

JSON is by far the fastest to parse, since it *IS* JavaScript.

Application frameworks like [EXT.JS](http://www.sencha.com/learn/using-the-data-package-in-sencha-touch/) are already doing this with great success.